# error in the " src " folder when importing project

Tags: eclipse, src

I imported a project in eclipse and am having this error in the "SRC" folder :

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1123x899q90/537/Wp1BJX.jpg)]

Comment: What are the actual errors? Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: make sure you have all jar in lib and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to check your package name? It might happen due to a different package name.